# Windows 8 screensaver defaults back to 1 minute no matter what I do

Tags: screensaver, windows-8

I can't figure out how to get my screen saver to turn on after a timeout period greater than 1 minute. Everytime I set it in display preferences and click "apply" it defaults back to 1 minute. I even tried specifying it in policy editor, no luck.

Comment: No, no problem on any of my W8 installs. You should edit your question to ask for a solution rather than " anyone else having this problem"

Answer (score 1):

Open regedit.exe and edit the registry key manually. The key you are looking for is in  HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop and is called ScreenSaveTimeOut, double click on it and specify a value in seconds, the default should be 60 seconds.Reboot after you have changed it.